# Log4j create daily log when no activity

Tags: java, logging, log4j

My log4j.xml looks like the following:

```
<appender name="DEBUG_APPENDER" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="./logs/debug/debug.log" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p|%m%n"/>
        </layout>
        <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMin" value="DEBUG"/>
            <param name="levelMax" value="WARN" />
            <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true"/>
        </filter>
    </appender>
```

This config works perfectly, until there is an activity that can be logged.
My goal is to have a `.log` file for each day, even if there was nothing to be logged (with a message maybe, like `"nothing happened, but log4j still works"`). Is it possible using `log4j` and keep my current config?